# Laravel, Fetching image from public/uploads folder

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.1

Controller :

```
public function index()
{
    if (!file_exists("uploads/profiles/".\Auth::User()->id.".jpeg")) {
        $image_content = File::get("uploads/profiles/default.jpg");
        $image =  response($image_content, 200)->header('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
        $size = getimagesize($image);
        $aspectratio = $size[0]/$size[1];
        $img_thumbnail = Image::make($image)->resize(50*$aspectratio,50);
        $img_profile = Image::make($image)->resize(160*$aspectratio,160);
        $imgname = \Auth::User()->id;
        $img_thumbnail->save('uploads/thumbnails/'.$imgname.".jpeg");
        $img_profile->save('uploads/profiles/'.$imgname.".jpeg");
}
```

Error : : failed to open stream: No such file or directory.

Actually, I want to fetch the default.jpg image and save it to two other folders with different extension.

Comment: @zkanoca That won't do anything.

Comment: The output you're seeing is correct. You need to have the response serve the right `Content-Type` header though.

Comment: Are you using a Mac or a Linux or Windows ?

Comment: I think you need to give a proper permission to your folder, that you want to output the image into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        if( !file_exists('uploads/thumbnails/'. $folder)){
            @mkdir('uploads/thumbnails/'. $folder, 0755);
        }
        if( !file_exists('uploads/profiles/'. $folder)){
            @mkdir('uploads/profiles/'. $folder, 0755);
        }

        $img = 'uploads/profiles/'. \Auth::User()->id. '.jpeg';
        if ( !file_exists($img)){
            $save_extension = '.jpeg';
            Image::make($img)
                ->resize(50, null, function ($constraint) {
                    $constraint->aspectRatio();
                })->save('uploads/thumbnails/' . \Auth::User()->id . $save_extension);
            Image::make($img)
                ->resize(160, null, function ($constraint) {
                    $constraint->aspectRatio();
                })->save('uploads/profiles/' . \Auth::User()->id . $save_extension);
        }
```

http://image.intervention.io/api/resize

Comment: But, I have to fetch the default.jpg from the folder '/uploads/profiles/default.jpg' and then save it to another destination "'uploads/thumbnails/' . \Auth::User()->id .'.jpeg'. But in your solution I'm not able to fetch default.jpg .

Comment: `( !file_exists('uploads/profiles/'. \Auth::User()->id. '.jpeg')){
   $save_extension = '.jpeg';
   Image::make('/uploads/profiles/default.jpg')
    ->resize(50, null, function ($constraint) {
     $constraint->aspectRatio();
    })->save('uploads/thumbnails/' . \Auth::User()->id . $save_extension);
   Image::make('/uploads/profiles/default.jpg')
    ->resize(160, null, function ($constraint) {
     $constraint->aspectRatio();
    })->save('uploads/profiles/' . \Auth::User()->id . $save_extension);
  }`

Comment: Change Image::make($img) to Image::make('/uploads/profiles/default.jpg').

'/uploads/profiles/default.jpg' exists in folder ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function index()
{
    if (!file_exists("uploads/profiles/".\Auth::User()->id.".jpeg")) {
        $image = File::get("uploads/profiles/default.jpg");
        return response($image)->header('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have done this but I modified the question. And I'm stuck in this.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're have the right permission to `uploads/profiles/`

```
chmod -R 777 /uploads/profiles/
```

Comment: Yes, permission is already given to folder because I've already saved the photos in that folder. But here the problem is fetching the default.jpg and then saving it to other destination. And when I'm fetching the default.jpg it's coming in blob, not in proper image which is not working with getimagesize